# Не отображается картинка в a.menu:visited в CSS

Tags: html, css

При наведении, фокусе, visited, активации и псевдокселекторе link должно отображать рисунок. Visited не работает. Не знаю в чем причина. Вроде статистические псевдоселекторы идут до динамических (по правилу).

```css
a.menu:link {
  background: #fff url("4.png") center right no-repeat;
}
a.menu:visited {
  background: #fff url("2.png") center right no-repeat;
}
a.menu:hover {
  background: #fff url("1.png") center right no-repeat;
}
a.menu:focus:hover {
  background: #fff url("3.png") center right no-repeat;
}
a.menu:active:hover {
  background: #fff url("5.png") center right no-repeat;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
  <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>

  <a href="#" id="lar" class="menu">Головна</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu">Автор</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu">Новини</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu">Ресурси</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Только картинки, разумеется, недоступны. Вы можете их выложить на imgur (через кнопку прикрепления картинки в редакторе), а потом вставить нужные урлы в код.

Comment: Если не справитесь, ответьте в комментарии, помогу.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/QnMsS  http://imgur.com/a/vNJJC  http://imgur.com/a/i94iV   http://imgur.com/a/Jimbi   http://imgur.com/a/qrVbB  Как их выложить, чтобы было всем видно ?

Comment: В редакторе вопроса в панели над полем ввода есть иконка с горой и солнцем, у него ещё всплывающая подсказка `Изображение <img> Ctrl+G`.

Comment: И ещё: если вы обращаетесь к пользователю, ссылайтесь на него через собачку без пробелов (@NickVolynkin), чтобы ему уведомление пришло.

Answer (score 4):

Разработчики большинства браузеров [избегают](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/) использования background-images в ссылках с псевдоклассом :visited, потому что считают их нарушением приватности пользователей.

Comment: Оно же не сработает...

Comment: @Qwertiy, вы правы. Исправил ответ.